# Connection time out during map reduce process

Tags: hadoop

I am transferring data from one cluster to other cluster using distcp command.i am getting below problem during map reduce process:

**java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out**

I am using below command:

```
/home/hadoop/hadoop/bin/hadoop distcp -update -skipcrccheck "hftp://source:50070//hive/warehouse//tablename" "hdfs://destination:9000//hive/warehouse//tablename"
```

How can i solve this problem .Solutions will be appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to transfer data from one **HDFS** to another then why you are using **hftp** command?

**hftp** is for transfer data from ftp server into hdfs.

try this for **hdfs to hdfs**

```
/home/hadoop/hadoop/bin/hadoop distcp -update -skipcrccheck "hdfs://source:50070/hive/warehouse/tablename" "hdfs://destination:9000/hive/warehouse/tablename"
```

For **ftp to hdfs**, use the correct ftp address.